# Java: Is method name/signature resolution done statically (compile-time)?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, compilation

I encountered an interesting problem today which I thought was not possible in Java. I compiled my java code against version 2.6 of jgroups but used version 2.12 at runtime (tomcat web app deployment). I got the following error

```
org.jgroups.Message.<init>(Lorg/jgroups/Address;Lorg/jgroups/Address;Ljava/io/Serializable;)
```

Assuming that the API would have change since then, I thought of porting my code to jgroups-2.12, but to my surprise the code compiled fine with jgroups-2.12 and when I replaced the new jar (without changing a single line in my code, just compiling against jgroups-2.12 instead of jgroups-2.6), it worked perfectly fine.

I later realized that the constructor `Message(Address, Address, Serializable)` in 2.6 was changed to Message(Address, Address, Object) in 2.12. This means at runtime, the JVM was trying to locate the exact same method and was failing to do so.

Does this mean that Java compiler embeds the exact method name and precise arguments while compiling and a method with broader arguments won't work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly right - the exact signature is bound at compile-time, and that's what gets included in the bytecode.

In fact, this even includes the return type, which isn't included in signatures for things like overloading purposes.

Fundamentally, if you change anything about an existing public API member, that will be a breaking change. You can get away with some language-only changes, such as changing a `String[]` parameter to a `String...` parameter, or introducing generics (in *some* cases, if the erasure is compatible with the previous code), but that's pretty much it.

[Chapter 13](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/binaryComp.html) of the Java Language Specification is all about binary compatibility - read that for more information. But in particular, from [section 13.4.14](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/binaryComp.html#13.4.14):

> Changing the name of a formal parameter of a method or constructor does not impact pre-existing binaries. Changing the name of a method, the type of a formal parameter to a method or constructor, or adding a parameter to or deleting a parameter from a method or constructor declaration creates a method or constructor with a new signature, and has the combined effect of deleting the method or constructor with the old signature and adding a method or constructor with the new signature (see §13.4.12).

Comment: Even adding generics can mess things up, if the generic you add has a different bound than the old code. That's why generics have the somewhat obscure `<T extends SomeClass & SomeInterface>` option -- so you can "manually" specify the erasure, and thus bytecode compatibility, of the generic.

Comment: @yshavit: Yes, you'd have to be careful - will edit to make that clearer.

Answer (score 5):

> Does this mean that Java compiler embeds the exact method name and precise arguments while compiling and a method with broader arguments won't work?

Exactly. You can also see this from the error message you got:

```
org.jgroups.Message.<init>(Lorg/jgroups/Address;Lorg/jgroups/Address;Ljava/io/Serializable;)
```

The complete signature is contained here, and the runtime looks for a perfect match.

There are also several other occasions when changing an API breaks binary compatibility in Java, but not source compatibility, for example when you change a primitive type to its boxed variant or vice versa. As pointed out by Jon, only changes in Generics (but not even all changes) and using the VarArgs syntax do not affect runtime method resolution, as both are only compiler features and do not affect the bytecode.

This also means that when you introduce an overload of a method in a new library version, this overload will only be used by callers compiled with the new version. Old binaries will still call the old method, even if their argument types would better fit the new overload.

For library designers it is thus sometimes advisable to do not change the signatures of existing methods, but only add new overloads (and let the old methods forward to the new ones so that it doesn't matter which one is called). Of course the disadvantage is that all these overloads obscure the real API and and make understanding the API more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Well Java compiler has to put exact method name and precise arguments in the compiled file to figure out later which class to load and which method to call. As else there is no way to precisely call the requested method.